# Pine Script: Overlay custom indicator onto price chart

Tags: math, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have developed a custom indicator with Pine Script and now I want to overlay the indicator onto the price chart but I am struggeling.

The indicator calculates a value X (white) and an average of that value Y (red). In the next step I now want to have the indicator shown on the price chart but X should now be replaced with price and Y should maintain the same distance to X/price.

In the picture the yellow line shows how the result should look like. If X (white) is below Y (red) then the yellow line should be below price. If X (white) is above Y (red) then the yellow line should be above price. If X and Y values are equal, then the yellow line should be equal to price.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXoGf.png)

If you have any further questions or need any further information please ask.

Best regards,
Hendrik

I tried the overlay=true function but that just prompts the overlay to the price panel.